# Overloading of operators with class instance as right-hand side

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to do overload to * operator in my Matrix class.

I have one that make it if it is Matrix*something, (int, double...)

i'm searching for one that make it for the opposite side i.e something*Matrix

this is what i tried

```
template<class T>
bool operator*(Matrix<T>& other ){
Matrix<T> mat(other.rows,other.columns);
for(int i=0;i<other.rows;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<other.columns;j++){
        T temp=other.get(i,j);
        temp=temp*(this);
        mat.set(i,j,temp);
    }
}
return mat;
}
```

and this is what works for Matrix*something

```
 Matrix<T>& operator*(const T & num){
    Matrix<T> mat(rows,columns);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
            T temp=(matrix[i][j]);
            temp=temp*num;
            mat.set(i,j,temp);
        }
    }
    return mat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make it a non-member, that is you write outside of `Matrix` class:

```
template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator*(const T& num, const Matrix<T>& mat) {
    return mat * num; // invoke existing implementation of Matrix * something
}
```

Note that `operator*` should return result by value. There is a bug in your implementation, you return dangling reference to a local variable `mat`.

Note that this form requires `num` to be of type `T` so if, like in your example, you have

```
Matrix<Rational> mat;
mat = 3 * mat;
```

it won't compile because `3` is not `Rational`.

What you can do is use [identity trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26885239/3959454) to put `num` parameter in non-deduced context, so it will be converted from `int` to `Rational`:

```
template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator*(typename boost::mpl::identity<T>::type const& num, const Matrix<T>& mat) {
    return mat * num; // invoke existing implementation of Matrix * something
}
```

Where `identity` is just

```
template<typename T> 
struct identity { typedef T type; };
```

Or you can do just

```
template<class T, class U>
Matrix<T> operator*(const U& num, const Matrix<T>& mat) {
    return mat * num; // invoke existing implementation of Matrix * something
}
```

Comment: i tried this and i got some compilation error                   
main.cpp:71:5: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘Matrix<Rational>’)
  m=3*m;
     ^
main.cpp:71:5: note: candidate is:
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
Matrix.hpp:229:12: note: template<class T> Matrix<T>& operator*(const T&, const Matrix<T>&)
 Matrix<T>& operator*(const T& num,const Matrix<T> &matr){
            ^
Matrix.hpp:229:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:71:6: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘T’ (‘int’ and ‘Rational’)
  m=3*m;
      ^

Comment: @keiloda It's kinda self-explanatory - `3` is `int` and not `Rational` so types mismatch.