# Why is this substitution of variadic template parameter failing ? (pack before fixed arguments)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Here is a minimal example triggering the compilation error:

```
#include <utility>
void foo(int, double, int)
{}

template <class... Args>
void post_forwarder(void(*fun)(Args..., int), Args&&... aArgs)
{
    fun(std::forward<Args>(aArgs)..., 5);
}

int main()
{
    post_forwarder(foo, 6, 6.1); // Compilation error on instantiation
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect the problem is related to the fact that the variadic template parameter is expanded in the function type before the fixed int parameter, but if it is the case I cannot find a good rationale for it.

The error reported by Clang 3.6 is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'post_forwarder'
note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction
```

Comment: Can you post the error? It would be helpful.

Comment: As an aside, deduced `Args&&...` forwarding to a function pointer expected `Args...` isn't a good plan.  Just making sure you know that.

Comment: @Yakk I must admit I could really use some more details regarding the point you are raising :)

Comment: @adn Forwarding reference types are rarely exactly what you'd use in a completely different bit of code to represent the variables.  You are using forwarding reference deduced types from variables `A...` to match against a function pointer that is not generated from those variables.  Think about the 4 cases of forwarding rsference deduction, and what type the corresponding function pointer must be.  If this makes no sense, brush up on what forwarding references *do* (it is not magic), or stop using them in anything but the simplest of contexts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Argument deduction fails here:

```
template <class... Args>
void post_forwarder(void(*fun)(Args..., int), Args&&... aArgs)
                           //  ^^^^^^^
```

for the general rule that parameter packs have to be at the end to be deducible. The usual solution is to wrap it in a non-deducible context, so that deduction isn't even attempted:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity {
    using type = T;
};

template <class... Args>
void post_forwarder(void(*fun)(typename identity<Args>::type..., int), Args&&... aArgs)
{
    fun(std::forward<Args>(aArgs)..., 5);
}
```

Comment: Well, technically speaking, the first `Args...` is already in a non-deduced context.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, but now it's a **super** non-deduced context. [Also, I don't have a full explanation]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885239/whats-the-point-of-boostmplidentityttype-here . As a sidenote I really would prefer an alias for `identity` in these contexts, like `dont_deduce`, so even if I don't understand the mechanism at least I know what the purpose is.

Comment: @T.C. If it's a non deduced context then why does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void post_forwarder(F f, Args&&... aArgs) {
    f(std::forward<Args>(aArgs)..., 5);
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3b609ff41f0669a)

Comment: It does work, but the question is to try to understand why the proposed minimal example is not working ? (Since it is extracted from a way more complex system, where your proposed alternative cannot replace the expected functionality).

Comment: @AdN Sorry, I had some important stuff and couldn't reply. It's a non deducable context, that's why it fails. But you've already have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Rewritten answer:

The form `Args..., int` doesn't allow to deduce `Args...`.

Comment: Are you sure ? There is an explicit last `int` in `fun` signatures, I would expect it to limit `Args...` deduction to the first 2 parameters.