# Non-deduced context like 'boost::mpl::identity<T>::type' in standard library?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, type-deduction

Cosider the following example I digged up [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885239/whats-the-point-of-boostmplidentityttype-here)

```
  template<typename T, typename Pred> 
  T const & clamp ( T const& val, 
    typename boost::mpl::identity<T>::type const & lo, 
    typename boost::mpl::identity<T>::type const & hi, Pred p )
  {
//    assert ( !p ( hi, lo ));    // Can't assert p ( lo, hi ) b/c they might be equal
    return p ( val, lo ) ? lo : p ( hi, val ) ? hi : val;
  }
```

where `typename boost::mpl::identity<T>::type` prevents the compiler from deducing T based on the type of the second and the third argument. This comes very handy for me, but I cannot use the `Boost Library` (please do not give me a hard time on that, as it is already a hard time because of that).

The question is now is something equivallent in the standard library directly which I just cannot find?

Comment: if there's nothing in the standard, it wouldn't be difficult to implement it yourself: the [synopsis here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/identity.html) is pretty much all there is to it

Comment: @kmdreko Totally right. I was just wondering about it being in the library as it struck me to be a nice thing to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++20 will have [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity). But you don't really have to wait for the standard library to have it. Its entire implementation is:

```
template< class T >
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

template< class T >
using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`boost::mpl::identity`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/identity.html) is a fairly straight-forward template that only provides a `type` identical to the provided template parameter.

It can be implemented as follows:

```
template <typename X>
struct identity
{
    typedef X type;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

`std::common_type_t<T>` works. [From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

> If `sizeof...(T)` is one (i.e., T... contains only one type T0), the member type names the same type as `std::common_type<T0, T0>::type` if it exists; otherwise there is no member type.

Thus, `std::common_type_t` will work for this

Comment: Not that I'd necessarily recommend it. It's not obvious that it does this